# Chat en tiempo real nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, socket, socket.io

Existe alguna forma de mandar un mensaje a un usuario en específico con nodejs y la librería socket.io.

En sí lo que deseo es que un usuario pueda contactar al administrador de mi página para cualquier duda o inconveniente. 
Si el administrador no está en línea, el mensaje que el usuario mande deberá de ser mostrado cuando el admin se logee.

Espero haberme dado a entender.
Necesito ayuda :(

O si existiera otra forma de hacerlo (**usuario -->admin**) si me la pudieran decir por favor.

Comment: De existir, existe. Las verdaderas preguntas son ¿has investigado algo?¿has visto la documentación oficial de socket.io?¿has intentado algo en código? Si alguna respuesta es "no", conviértela en "sí" y procede a editar la pregunta agregando tus intentos, muéstrale a la comunidad lo que has investigado, con eso la comunidad te tomará atención. Te comento que las preguntas que carecen de código y que suenan a ticket para el área de desarrollo, se quedan con muchos "vistos" durante un tiempo indefinido.

Comment: Si existe con el metodo io.to.